# What is the purpose of ApplicationBuilder.Properties?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

What is the purpose of the `ApplicationBuilder.Properties` collection?  Why not simply use `HttpContext.Items`?

About the only thing I can come up with is if you want to pass objects from one piece of middleware to another, but again, you could just as easily use `HttpContext.Items` for that.

I suppose there is an argument for reducing scope.. if an object is only of use for middleware, why pollute `HttpContext.Items`?

Back in the Owin days, we would use Owin properties, and you could get these properties in your app by using `GetOwinContext()`, but there doesn't seem to be any equivalent of that in the asp.net middleware.  So that doesn't seem like it holds the answer.

I did some searching through the framework and couldn't find anything using it within the framework itself.  I might have missed something though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the purpose of ApplicationBuilder.Properties?

According to [source code on Github](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/87cd79d6fc54bb4abf07c1e380cd7a9498a78612/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/IApplicationBuilder.cs#L27)

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a key/value collection that can be used to share data between middleware.
/// </summary>
IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; }
```

to speculate about anything else would be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Ahh.  I should have gone to the source for sure.  The API documentation didn't mention this.  In fact, it didn't have any comments other than the actual signature.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, I also went to docs first and found nothing in terms of explanations so went looking in the source code. I get more documentation from the source code than from the *"official"* docs